# Married in Germany

Tags: visa, marriage

I am Australian and I have married my German husband in Germany on a tourist visa. I have been here for 7 weeks. I have moved here fully. I came on a one-way ticket. My tourist visa only has 90 days on it.

I have my German marriage certificate but what now? Will I be able to stay here as I am living here now? I have done all my papers as asked. What visa will I apply for and during the time my visa is being processed, will I be able to stay in in Germany with my husband and maybe study and work? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You are lucky. And let me stress this. Lucky. Because this is research you do *before* you move continents.

As you are Australian, you are *exempt* from the normal rules that apply. You do *not* have to go back to your home country and apply from there.

- You need to go to your landlord (Vermieter) and register with them.
- With the paper you got from your landlord, you go to the civil administrations office (Bürgerbüro) of your city and register there.
- With *that* paper you go to the foreigners office of your city (Ausländerbehörde) get into a long line with all the others and when you get an appointment, you show your marriage certificate and passport. You will also need to prove a sufficient grasp of the German language (commonly called "Level A1"), either through a certificate *and* a quick oral test there (basically just the clerk asking you simple questions like your name and birth date in German and expecting you to answer in German to make sure your certificate isn't a total self-printed fraught) or if you actually do speak good German, you can demonstrate it there without the need for a certificate (for example by just going through all of this in German yourself).

You need to be at all those steps *in person*. I'm not sure if your husband is *required*, but it will help *a lot* to have somebody who knows his or her way around the German bureaucracy.

If you don't know German yet, the biggest problem might be A1. Try to find a course, work on it and try to do all that stuff above *immediately*. German *Amt*s are ok, as long as you are prepared, do everything they say to the letter and stay in touch and work something out with them. If you come on the last day and something is missing, that's not going to end well.

Comment: I will to my local Ausländerbehörde next week with my marriage certificate and all the other paper but nothing proving that I can speak German and I will not have enough time to get it. Will they still let me apply for a Visa to stay or will it be bad news ???

Comment: As far as I know, you can only apply with A1 or equivalent. However, if you already got an appointment, go and talk to them. Ask them what you can do. Maybe the have the power to make exceptions and allow you a longer stay while you get your A1. But that's just a guess, I don't know.

Comment: It's not by appointment. We were told we just have to go there and wait our turn. I have read online on EXPATICA that you dont have to prove your language ability if you are a national of Australia Canada Israel Japan the republic of Korea new Zealand and USA. is the accurate information????

Comment: Sadly, that's incorrect. You have to read very carefully. You don't have to prove language ability if the person you are moving *to* is from one of those countries. For example you are moving to be with your AUS husband already in Germany.  You also don't have to prove it if the person you are moving to is from the EU, or is German but you are moving to a different EU state. Because that is covered by EU law. But moving to a German in Germany is covered by *German* law and that says you need an A1.

Comment: It makes no sense that it would be easier for both of you to legally move to a country *neither* of you speaks the language (say Denmark) than you moving to your German husband, but that's the current state of laws. EU law that would permit it is superseded by German law for Germans in Germany.

Comment: The waiting in line part is correct though.

Comment: I understand. Thank for pointing that out.

Comment: My husband is definitely a citizen of the European union. This is one of the points I dont need to prove my language if...You or your spouse are a citizen of the European Union or have 
exercised your right to free movement as a German.

Comment: If he is a citizen of the EU *and not a German citizen* that applies (if for example he's a French citizen and living in Germany). If he is a citizen of the EU *and a German citizen* then local (German) law takes precedence. Having exercised the right to free movement means you lived in another EU country together for at least 2 years and now want to move back to Germany. That, too is governed by EU law because there is no specific German law for that.

Comment: Okay thanks. So I will not have time to prove my German language and I speak no German yet. I'm here on my tourist Visa with on 90days and in 3 weeks that's up but being  married with me German marriage certificate now will they send me home without any language skills. My biggest worry is they make me leave as I have fully moved here.

Comment: You don't need the A1 certificate yet. But you need a letter of confirmation you have already signed up for a German A1 course, from the course provider. The *Ausländerbehörde* will then grant you some months to finish that course.

Comment: And if I do that and then complete the A1 course when i have the A1 certificate do I go back to the Ausländerbehörde and then they let me apply for a Visa?? Also does anyone know how long and how much the A1 course is ???? Thank you.

Comment: Please don't mix terms up. *Visa* is something you need for entering Germany and staying here as a tourist. For anything else, you need a *Aufenthaltserlaubnis* or better. That's what you get at the *Ausländerbehörde* when you show them your marriage certificate and German course subscription.

Comment: The German A1 course is about 50 hours, held in 8–10 weeks. With your private tutor at your side, you should be able to get much more fluent than A1 in that time. Such a course will cost you about 5€ per hour, the test fee is about 100€.

Comment: Yes but my tourist Visa is up soon and I only have my marriage certificate which still does not allow me to stay in Germany more than 90days. I was told by the German and Australian embassy both here and in Australia to be very careful not to exceed my 90days. I need some sort of Visa to stay not just a extention. I live in here in Germany now. I think it's called a family reunion Visa. It's to join your spouse in Germany.

Comment: You don't need a Visa, because you are already in Germany. A Visa is a travel document. You don't want to travel to Germany. You want to stay here. You need an *Aufenthaltserlaubnis*. And you will get it when you have the needed papers.

Comment: Okay so should I apply for a A1 German course before I go to them and show them I am applied somewhere becuase I know I will not have any german language certificate by next week. Will this be the easiest thing to do. If I dont ro this will they sent me back until I show I'm doing a course

Comment: Correct. You have to show them you signed up for a course and invested time and money into learning German. Then, they can tick that field on their paperwork and you are okay.

Comment: Oh, and if you are a student, go to the *Sprachenzentrum* of your university. They often offer language courses **for free**.

Comment: @Janka If by "personal tutor" you mean the OP's husband, be aware that "having a language as a mother tongue", and "being able to teach that language to a non-native speaker" are *very* different.  The husband can say when pronunciation is wrong (but probably not explain how to produce the right sound), and provide better vocabulary, but they won't be able to teach the grammar.

Comment: That's why they are only a tutor, not a teacher.