# Language A1 certificate

Tags: language

I am going to the Ausländerbehörde next week with my German marriage certificate, but I do not have an A1 German certificate. I was thinking of applying at a local school that starts August 15th, 2018 so I can get my A1 certificate. I will take the proof that I have paid and applied to a school with me to the Ausländerbehörde, but from next week until August 15th is a few weeks, and even longer to complete the classes tests and receive my A1 certificate.

My question is: will they let me stay, and give me an extra few months to complete this course and prove my basic German language ability (until about the end of September)?

Comment: How good is your German at the moment?  A (British) friend got his citizenship without any formal certification of his German skills. Reasons this may not apply to you: a) His application was backed by the former Bürgermeister of his Gemeinde; b) he is the local choir master; c) this is rural Baden-Württemberg.

Comment: So: can you [edit] your question to indicate your current German skills and where you are from.

Comment: I only can pretty much say my name please and thank you so not good at all. The reason I ask is becuase I married here on my tourist Visa which is only 90days I only have about 3 4 weeks left until it's up. I am Australian citizen and just want to apply for a resdince permit here in german

Comment: Right, so you *are* going to need to improve your German.  If you are Australian, can I suggest you need to improve the English of your question too?  It's currently very hard to read.  Some paragraphs would help.

Comment: Martin Bonner it seems like your not going to be any help. I am fully aware I need improve my German. I dont need information I already know thanks and as for my English i'm sure if you read my question you can understand what i am asking. Is the time from next week till August 15th 2018 to long for them to accept my application at a German school (which starts on August 15th 2018) to get my A1 CERTIFICATE as I am on a tourist Visa which is up in 3 weeks ????

Comment: I can only apply for a residence permit if I at least have a A1 certificate and next week when I go to the Ausländerbehörde I will not have one and I am tight with time becuase my tourist visa is nearly up. I hope it's easier to understand now. I also pointed out I am Australian becuase I know it depends where you're from in the world. Also I cant just not go to the Ausländerbehörde and instead just study and get my A1 CERTIFICATE becuase it is illegal to work or study on a tourist Visa and my 90days will be up anyway if I was to do this

Comment: Hi Maz. Please take a deep breath and try to relax. Everyone here is a volunteer. Answers to questions here on Expats often can affect someone's life so we want to be sure that your circumstances are clear and that we understand your question.

Comment: I appreciate everyone trying to help. I am still very unaware of what I must do myself at the Ausländerbehörde with not having and basic German language certificate and not having enough time to get one as I will go to the Ausländerbehörde next week with all my papers but that one. I am tight with time becuase I married here in Germany on my tourist Visa. I have tried to call them but very hard to get through with there working hours.

Comment: With respect to your [other question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/14001/married-in-germany) you're absolutely right to add the A1 course application to the documents list. Showing effort to gain something is as important as having it. Meanwhile teach yourself basic A1 expressions, learn how to introduce yourself and train your ear to simple questions (name, birth, nationality). Officials could be friendly enough to overlook some corners, but you need to show effort and ability to integrate - starting with learning some German on your own.